# OpenCV: 3D Matrix on GPU

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, gpu

I was wondering if it is possible to upload a 3-dimensional matrix to the gpu to work with it? I have a sequence of images all having the same resolution (around 100 frames); now I want to upload them to the gpu using OpenCV's .upload function and do a few computations on them.

The simple approach would be to just create a GPuMat for each frame and upload them sequentially but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon how your algorithm works, you might be able to simply concatenate the images in one of the existing image dimensions instead of trying to create a "3D" image. For instance, if you had two frames of 640x480 images, make a single 640x960 image as your image to be sent to the GPU.

Comment: Ok I think I'll try this. The question is if it is faster to allocate such a big array and copy all frames at once it to it or if it is better to just allocate two small arrays and memcpy the data. I will check this. Cheers